# Modern versions of Meld can't compare local folder with remote folder (in /run/user/1000/gvfs/) - can we fix it?

Tags: mount, ssh, sftp, 21.10, meld

When I use Meld 3.20.4-1 on Ubuntu MATE 21.10 I can't compare local and remote folders using below steps:

1. Connect to some share with Caja - press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, enter `sftp://user@hostname.local` in the address-bar to get the folder mounted to `/run/user/1000/gvfs/sftp:host=hostname.local,user=user/`
2. Open terminal and run Meld from it to compare folder pair:

   ```
   meld /run/user/1000/gvfs/sftp:host=hostname.local,user=user/home/user/Desktop ~/Desktop
   ```

As the result I get

> ```
> $ meld /run/user/1000/gvfs/sftp:host=hostname.local,user=user/home/user/Desktop ~/Desktop
> Usage:
>  meld Start with an empty window
>  meld <file|folder> Start a version control comparison
>  meld <file> <file> [<file>] Start a 2- or 3-way file comparison
>  meld <folder> <folder> [<folder>] Start a 2- or 3-way folder comparison
>
> Error: remote folder “/run/user/1000/gvfs/sftp:host=hostname.local,user=user/home/user/Desktop” not supported
> ```

Can we do something with this problem on user-level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really such comparison is broken [since 20.04 LTS](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/meld/+bug/1869482), so we need to wait for the [fix upstream](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/meld/-/issues/497).

Temporary workaround is to use [SSHFS](https://github.com/libfuse/sshfs) as follows:

1. Install `sshfs` package by

   ```
   sudo apt-get install sshfs
   ```
2. Create temporary mount-point for remote location

   ```
   mkdir ~/sshfs
   sshfs user@hostname.local:/home/user/Desktop ~/sshfs
   ```
3. Compare local folder with the remote using the same Meld version

   ```
   meld ~/sshfs ~/Desktop
   ```

   Do some synchronization.
4. Unmount remote location and optionally remove mountpoint

   ```
   umount ~/sshfs
   # rmdir ~/sshfs
   ```

Answer (score 1):

**The workaround by N0rbert does not really work. As Meld uses Gnome’s GIO, which detects it as a “remote file system” anyway. A basic comparison might work, but you’ll be running into trouble as soon as you’re trying to actually merge things. Like deleting a directory.**

And if you force it, by patching the detection out of Meld, like I did for this test, it asks GIO to delete the directory, and GIO fails because “the directory is not empty”. In other words, the delete function apparently only works recursively for local file systems. Which is insane, as Linux’s VFS by default does not make this distinction between file system implementations and that is kinda its entire point.

So apparently, GIO doesn’t use those standard Linux VFS interfaces that would have already worked, but its own hackish and by Linux/Unix standards defective solution (partially on top of VFS, but making it worse).
As an old time Linux user, I can tell you that this is due to being run by developers who came over from Windows, and think everything has to work like Windows, because they are either to young or actively refuse to learn the basic conventions and ideas of Unix/Linux, and then are doomed to re-invent Unix … badly.
(Same reason for containers, the implementation of systemd [not the general idea, which is fine], the kernels’s network interface implementation, anyone asking for “Linux On The Desktop”, the way Steam is “implemented” on Linux [It’s just a Windows app inside of a custom Wine instance, ignoring all Linux conventions], etc.)

**Meld itself has this comment in the source code:**

```
# TODO: Deleting remote folders involves reimplementing
# shutil.rmtree for gio, and then calling
# self.recursively_update().
```

(Or… you know… just use the standard VFS/POSIX interface like normal people.)

**So the only solution here, is to use proper Linux tools**, or go all the way and run Windows/MacOS instead of a tool running on the former that wants to be the latter. ;)

I’d recommend **Kdiff3**, but that has its own problem, as it fails to copy new files from local to remote, at least in my case of directory comparison with sshfs from KDEConnect on an Android phone.

Other than that, `rsync`, `dirdiff` and `vimdiff` (or `vim` with the `DirDiff` extension) et al would be native and quicker solutions, **but they are of course not as comfortable for manual directory merging with them, which is why ever people like me are forced to using Meld/Kdiff3.**

---

**ADDENDUM:** Here is the core bug:

[Allow to recursively remove directory (#2258) · Issues · GNOME / GLib · GitLab](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/-/issues/2258)

An additional problem this shows, is that if the remote file system has a ”Trash”, `g_file_trash` could be used, as that apparently *does* work recursively, even remotely. … I have still no idea why they actively excluded one implementation from recursive deletes even though from a user space perspective, there is literally no difference.